# Is there a WineHQ Equivalent that runs Mac programs on Windows?

Tags: windows, osx, virtual-machine

Been looking for an equivalent to WineHQ that instead lets you run Mac applications on Windows. All I'm seeing so far is Virtual Environments. Anyone know if a tool like this exists? Thanks!